# Lucene StandardQueryParser wrongly parses Date Strings

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have created a StandardQueryParser to parse my filter queries for search. The parser perfectly parses Numeric range queries and the search provides the expected results.

But if I like to query a DateTime String the parser returns an unexpected value, cutting of everthing except the year. Example: `date:["2021-06-04T18:00:00Z" TO "2021-06-04T19:00:00Z"] -> date:[2021 TO 2021]` where the first is the query on the client and the second is the query after the query parser parses the query.
The expected query would be `date:[1622822400 TO 1622826000]`, transformed to the correct epoch timestamp.

For the configuration of the PointsConfigMap I used the following code which iterates over the schema and extracts the numeric types.

```java
private void buildQueryParser(SolrCore core) {
    standardQueryParser = new StandardQueryParser(contextFilterQueryAnalyzer);
    Map<String, PointsConfig> pointsConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(var entry : core.getLatestSchema().getFields().entrySet()) {
        var type = entry.getValue().getType();
        if (type.isPointField()) {
            PointsConfig pointsConfig = extractPointsConfig(type);
            if (pointsConfig != null) {
                pointsConfigMap.put(entry.getKey(), pointsConfig);
            }
        }
    }
    standardQueryParser.setPointsConfigMap(pointsConfigMap);
}

private PointsConfig extractPointsConfig(FieldType type) {
    switch (type.getNumberType()) {
        case DATE:
        case LONG:
            return new PointsConfig(new DecimalFormat(), Long.class);
        case INTEGER:
            return new PointsConfig(new DecimalFormat(), Integer.class);
        case FLOAT:
            return new PointsConfig(new DecimalFormat(), Float.class);
        case DOUBLE:
            return new PointsConfig(new DecimalFormat(), Double.class);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `contextFilterQueryAnalyzer` is initialized as: `new TokenizerChain(new KeywordTokenizerFactory(Collections.EMPTY_MAP), null)`

How to configure the StandardQueryParser correctly to parse DateTime Strings into Timestamps?

Comment: Is there more (relevant code) to your `PointsConfig` type? I find it weird to see `LONG` and `DATE` being treated the same way.

Comment: There is no additional code. I guess that there is a special Date NumberFormat class which handles the transformation but couldn't find out yet.